# Does writing If (Function) {return function} execute the function twice?

Tags: php

In Php if I write something like

```
If ($this->that()){ return $this->that()}
```

Does it execute `$this->that()` twice? Or does that parser figure it out and reduce it to 1 call?

Trying to keep code clean if possible, but don't want to double by execution time for sake of one variable assignment.

Comment: why dont you try it? echo "FOO"; in the function....

Comment: Yes, it runs twice, which a trivial `function(){echo 1;}` could have told you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it executes twice.

To make it execute once, you should save it's value into a variable and return the variable:

```
if ($value = $this->that()) {
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: That's what I figured, but thought I'd double check! Thanks! I'll accept in a few minutes when I can!

Answer (score 1):

IF you're calling the function twice, its gonna evaluate twice.

Answer (score 1):

It will definitely execute twice.

Perhaps you're looking for [function_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)? I'm not sure if your `if` statement is intended to determine if the function exists or does not return false.